# What is a best way to fork a substrate pallet?

Tags: pallet, pallet-treasury

**Context**:

i'm building a "sub-treasury" pallet, and for it, i'd like to start from the existing substrate's pallet_treasury.

**Problem**:

In Cargo.toml, there is relative paths (like `sp-io = {version=...... path="../../sp-io"}`
Obviously had to change it, but then in lib.rs, i had a loooooot of errors.

those errors are mainly "the trait frame_support::[something i can't `use`]::[the trait] is not implemented for [Proposal<...> or #[pallet::call]]

for example purpose, here is the first error given by cargo:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `pallet::Call<T, I>: frame_support::parity_scale_codec::WrapperTypeEncode` is not satisfied
   --> pallets/sub_treasury/src/lib.rs:296:12
    |
296 |     #[pallet::call]
    |               ^^^^ the trait `frame_support::parity_scale_codec::WrapperTypeEncode` is not implemented for `pallet::Call<T, I>`
    |
...
note: required by a bound in `frame_support::Callable::Call`
   --> /home/erudyx/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/19162e4/frame/support/src/dispatch.rs:56:38
    |
56  |     type Call: UnfilteredDispatchable + Codec + Clone + PartialEq + Eq;
    |                                         ^^^^^ required by this bound in `frame_support::Callable::Call`
```

**Question**:

I'd like to know if there is a proper way to fork a pallet. Is there a specific branch to fork from ? A specific repo ? Is there a place where the procedure is documented ?

Comment: Please paste here the first compiler error exactly as it appears.

Comment: To have a correct format, i added the first error on the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested these steps and they work just fine:

1. Copy the pallet folder you want to a new location. (I used my desktop)
2. Navigate to the copied pallet folder.
3. Modify `Cargo.toml` replacing `path = "..."` with `git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git"`

   - You can use the regular expression `path = "[\S]+"` to match on the path string.
4. Run `cargo build` in the folder.

If you run into any compiler issues, make sure to update your rust compiler:

- `rustup update`

EDIT:

As noted by the author, it is critical if you are building a forked crate in a larger Substrate project, that all versions / references to Substrate must be the same. You can quickly run into compiler errors if you have one crate which depends on one version of Substrate, and another crate depend on a different version.

Comment: The problem was unmatching version. I'm accepting your answer because it clearly answer to the title question, but could you please note on your response to be careful of which version of the pallet we're taking, so people wont do the same mistake as me ? Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Okey follow this steps

1. in the src/cargo.toml include the pallet ( its repo and which version you want to use)
2. Then include the pallet into workspace project/ cargo.toml -> There is workspace vector , include the path to your pallet
3. Then include it in the runtime/cargo.toml
4. Then import it in the runtime/src -> Then implement the neccessary trait require by the pallet. You can see example from balances pallet how its implemented in the runtime and Then Include it in the construct_runtime!

Comment: I followed your steps (i already did 1 and 2), but i still have the errors. I made some clarification in the OP about the errors i encounter

Comment: You are getting error from your pallet as per the error message and not from importing the pallet. So checkout your code inside pallet treasury. Or you can share your repo for more clarification.

Comment: i didn't change anything in pallet_treasury code, I only copied it, pasted in /pallet/sub-treasury and renamed as it should.

 I have this version: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/treasury

Comment: yes but the errors are from sub_treasury pallet. So the treasury pallet is fine

Comment: Yea but sub_treasury is the treasury pallet renamed renamed, if i let it be called treasury, i have the same error

Comment: can you point me to your repo (or is it closed source?)

Comment: sadly it's a closed source.
But i understood my problem, the treasury version i took was on master, and the version of substrate i was using was 0.9.16, so a different one. i just took the treasury code from polkadot-v0.9.16 branch on substrate, and now it's working just fine :)